# Is there a performance difference between using router-outlet and ngIf

Tags: angular

Imagine that I'm using ngIf to render (or create) a component and I'm switching between components based on ngIf (or ngSwitch). Regardless of the pattern concerns (though I think it's a better pattern to use router while switching between components), in case of performance, would there be any performance gain that if I use router-outlets instead of ngIf blocks (or vice versa)?

**Visualization**

*using ngIf*

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition === a">
   <a-component></a-component>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="condition === b">
   <b-component></b-component>
</ng-container>
```

*using router-outlet*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the component, In either case(router outlet or ngIf) the component gets created and destroyed.

If your component is heavy then switching between components too frequently may lead to a performance issue.

BTW with **heavy** I mean javascript memory consumption and DOM repaint.

Memory problems can be avoided just make sure you don't have memory leaks, but DOM repaint can't be avoided if you change DOM too frequently then there will be a performance issue.

**One solution to avoid DOM repaint is to use `hidden` instead of `ngIf`.**

Comment: Yes, as I know, ngIf directly removes the block from the DOM tree, in these cases sometimes hidden property becomes more performant. I guess there's no significant performance difference between router and ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I have been working with Angular for almost a year now and this is my view:

Which to choose and why:

- I think this is only a question of how big the element you are trying to hide and display, if its is for e.g a container with some content or a card, `*ngIf` makes more sense, if its a large component with multiple elements and functionalities running through it, possibly has child components, using angular's routing makes more sense, mainly because of structure difference as someone above mentioned, angular routing organises your components very well in your app. Using `*ngIf` for big components will always come out messy.

Is there a performance difference?:

- It depends what routing method youre using, by default angular loads all your components immediately, and in this way there may be a performance difference. However if youre using their lazy-loading routing method to load your component/s, the components are not loaded until the module which contains them is called on your command, and in this case there would be no performance difference between them.

Checkout lazy-loading docx here: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Hope this helped :)

Comment: I use lazy loading in several places in my app, but I guess lazy loading will only lead to faster initialization of the page. Also, creating modules for the view blocks in the page is not a good pattern to solve problems (personal opinion).  As far as I see, while switching between pages, there's no significant performance difference between using ngIf and router. Thanks for your reply!